# Is there a conditional operator for setting a variable in C# to the value of another variable if the latter isn't null?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

Something like the ternary operator (?:) or the null coalescing operator (??). It seems silly to me to take up two lines and be so wordy when the other operators exist.

EDIT:
Since it's requested, here's two possible examples of what I hope that I can find

```
var variable ?= mightBeNull;
```

or

```
var variable = mightBeNull != null ? mightBeNull
```

Really, it's either something that can be used to assign a value, if it's not null, to a variable or an If without an Else packaged nicely in an operator.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would use it for? (e.g., Pretend `?=` was the operator; how would you use it?) I ask because you might be able to use `??` to accomplish your goal, while keeping things readable.

Answer (score 4):

The `??=` operator is [coming to C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

```
int? i = null; // i = null

i ??= 0; // i = 0
i ??= 1; // i = 0

// different ways of writing 'i ??= 0;':
i = i ?? 0;
if (i == null) i = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want this?

```
if (other != null)
    someVariable = other;
```

You could do the following, but I'd argue that the above is better due to clarity and possible side effects:

```
someVariable = other ?? someVariable;
```

The above might cause side effects if `someVariable` is a property and either the `get` or `set` can cause side effects; this shouldn't be important if your property follows the ordinary guidelines. Or, as Servy points out, even if it's a field, it could created different semantics in a multithreaded app. I should note that in the first example, you read `other` twice, which also has the potential for complexity to enter (though a smaller potential than the latter example).

Comment: Note that if `someVariable` is, say, a property, rather than a field, the then setting it to its current value may not be a noop.  It could do all sorts of things in the setter.  And even if it *is* a field, it could still create different semantics in a multithreaded app, involving rolling back a change in another thread, slicing a value, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is what you are looking for.

Let's say we have a function, `myFunction` that says whether the argument passed `input` is null or not. If `input` is null, it will return `"Input is null!"`, else it will return `"Input is not null"`.

This is the normal approach:

```
public String myFunction(string input) {  
    if (input == null)  
        return "Input is null!";  
    else  
        return "Input is not null";
}
```

And this is the other approach **(What you are looking for)**:

```
public String myFunction(string input) {
    return (input == null) ? "Input is null!" : "Input is not null";
}
```

It is called (?: conditional operator).

Answer (score 1):

To assign a value to a variable only if it is not null, you would need to use an `if`.  Neither the conditinal nor the null coalesce operators would do that.

```
if(somethingElse != null) something = somethingElse;
```

There is no specific operator in C# that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 C# there is a new operator called the [Null-Conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) that does what you are asking.  It is the ?. or ? operator.

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null 
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```

---

Currently useable in previous versions of C# but not an operator but rather a one liner would be to use the ? : statement 
[?: operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
AssingningTO = (someVar == null) ?  null: someVar; // if null assign null ELSE assign someVar
AssingningTO = (someVar == null) ?  String.Empth(): someVar; // if null assign empty string else someVar
```

Answer (score -4):

Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type, and an additional null value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question asked.